# Explain Mac Lane, CTFWM, page 109

Tags: category-theory

In Category Theory for the Working Mathematician, second edition, page 109 (near the bottom of the page) is said

> but all triangles formed by these projections need not commute ($f_n p_{n+1} \ne p_n$).

Please explain why they need not commute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation: $0=\varnothing$, $1=\{\varnothing\}$, $2=\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$.

Let's define the functor $F\colon\omega^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$ in the following way: $$F_i=\begin{cases}
2,i=0\\
1,i\ne0
\end{cases};$$
$$
f_i=\begin{cases}
\Delta_0,i=0\\
id(1),i\ne0
\end{cases}.$$
Then $(f_0\circ p_1)(1,0,0,\ldots)=0\ne 1=p_0(1,0,0,\ldots)$.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a product. Product is taken not on the cone $F$ but on the cone corresponding to (discrete) set $\omega$. Thus equalities related to the cone $F$ are not required.